# HSQLDB HAVING object not found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hsqldb

Hi there I am having trouble bringing a mysql query in hsqldb to work for a unit test.

Unfort I can't show you the real code. 
I tried to make it as simple as possible:

```
  SELECT A.id,
  (SELECT count(*) FROM SomeOtherTable) as myAlias
  FROM Orders A WHERE A.someKz = 2 HAVING 1 = myAlias;
```

Will result in

> user lacks privilege or object not found: MYALIAS

So my question is, how to access the variable `myAlias` in the `HAVING` clause?

This query might not look yousefull to you but it is very simplified. For Example there are serveral complex Subselects with variables.

UPDATE

This one has basically the same problem

```
SELECT A.id, (SELECT count(*) as anzahl1 FROM ABTable p WHERE p.Aid =  A.id   AND p.refNR > 0) as anz1,   (SELECT count(*) as anzahl1 FROM ABTable p WHERE p.Aid = A.id  ) as anz2,   (SELECT count(*) as anzahl1 FROM ABTable p WHERE p.Aid = A.id AND p.SID = 18 ) as anz3   FROM ABable A    WHERE
    A.someInt IN(1,2)
    AND A.someString > '20150308190127'
    AND(SELECT Count(*) FROM DTable D WHERE D.Aid = A.id ) = 0    HAVING anz1 = anz2 AND anz3 < anz2 ORDER BY someString ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: duplicate alias name will not be allowed. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12825_01/epm.111/esb_dbag/frameset.htm?dotnonuq.htm

Comment: @SkyWalker Where should the duplicated alias be?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example can be written as this for HSQLDB. It returns a result only if the Orders table contains a single row. But if the `1` is actually another expression in the SELECT list, you need to write it out:

```
SELECT A.id, 1 as myAlias
FROM Orders A WHERE A.someKz = 2 AND (SELECT count(*) FROM Orders) = 1

SELECT A.id, A.acol * 12 as myAlias
FROM Orders A WHERE A.someKz = 2 AND (SELECT count(*) FROM Orders) = A.acol *12
```

Your full query is far more complex. You should therefore write it with a wrapper SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT A.id, (SELECT count(*) as anzahl1 FROM ABTable p WHERE p.Aid =  A.id   AND p.refNR > 0) as anz1,   (SELECT count(*) as anzahl1 FROM ABTable p WHERE p.Aid = A.id  ) as anz2,   (SELECT count(*) as anzahl1 FROM ABTable p WHERE p.Aid = A.id AND p.SID = 18 ) as anz3   FROM ABable A
 WHERE A.someInt IN(1,2)
 AND A.someString > '20150308190127'
 AND(SELECT Count(*) FROM DTable D WHERE D.Aid = A.id ) = 0
) WHERE anz1 = anz2 AND anz3 < anz2 ORDER BY someString ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Could you explain that with the second example?

Comment: The second example shows how an expression can be used instead of the constant `1`. You said in a comment that the `1` is actually another alias.